# How can i create .png transparent image in GWT?

Tags: gwt

i want to Generate .png image in GWT

Does anyone know about this?

Comment: What do you mean "create"? As I know, GWT is for generating JavaScript from Java. Can you be a little more detailed?

Comment: create means, i want to Genarate the .png image using GWT ?

Comment: Do you mean convert another format to png or make an image from code?

Comment: What kinds of images?  Vector graphics? Pictures taken with cameras?  Graphs/plots produced by other software?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GWT 2.4, and HTML canvas, you can do it on the browser side. Create a canvas element, draw whatever you want on it and then get a data url which contains the image as png data. This will only work on browsers that support it (most modern browsers do, IE <= 8 won't support it as far as I know but you can use [explorercanvas](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/)).

Example code (**untested**):

```
Canvas canvas = Canvas.createIfSupported();

canvas.setCoordinateSpaceWidth(100);
canvas.setCoordinateSpaceHeight(100);

canvas.getContext2D().setStrokeStyle("black");
canvas.getContext2D().lineTo(100, 100);
canvas.getContext2D().stroke();

String pngDataUrl = canvas.toDataUrl("image/png");
Image image = new Image(pngDataUrl);
```

At the end of this code, `pngDataUrl` will have the png image encoded as a data url. `image` will display the canvas' contents as a regular PNG image in the browser.